# Stream pass through

Tags: c#, .net, stream

Considered we have two methods:

```
Task DownloadFromAToStreamAsync(Stream destinationStream);
Task UploadToBFromStreamAsync(Stream sourceStream);
```

Now we need to download content from A and upload it to B in a single operation.

One of the solutions:

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    await DownloadFromAToStreamAsync(stream);
    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    await UploadToBFromStreamAsync(stream);
}
```

But this solution requires the whole stream content to be loaded in memory.

How to solve the task more efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

Change the Download method to accept an additional size parameter which indicates how much to download. Then loop downloading and uploading untill a download returns an empty stream.